# ML docker 2-node cluster works fine but a third node when linked it fails

Tags: docker, marklogic

Going through ML manuals I was able to create a 2-node cluster in localhost, but when I try to add a 3rd node the browser keeps waiting and ultimately timeout. After clicking OK, it keeps loading.....
[image]

The steps are as follows that I followed (No docker compose used here) -

1. create a new MarkLogic container

   docker run -d --name=marklogic1 --hostname=marklogic1.local -p 8000-8002:8000-8002 marklogic:9.0-10.5-preinitialized
2. Create another MarkLogic container and link it to 1st one

   docker run -d --name=marklogic2 --hostname=marklogic2.local --link marklogic1:marklogic1 -p 18000-18002:8000-8002 marklogic:9.0-10.5-preinitialized
3. Go to localhost:8001 and follow the post-installation steps as per manual.
4. Go to localhost:18001 and follow the post-installation steps as per manual.
5. Successfully created 2-node cluster
6. Add a 3rd container and link it to all other ones

   docker run -d --name=marklogic3 --hostname=marklogic3.local --link marklogic1:marklogic1 --link marklogic2:marklogic2 -p 28000-28002:8000-8002 marklogic:9.0-10.5-preinitialized
7. login to localhost:28001 and try to follow the post-installation steps. The above screen is where my browser keeps waiting for input and ultimately timeout. See the above picture.

I tried increasing docker CPU and memory. 
[image]

But it didn't helped. Support needed.

Comment: Check the ErrorLog.txt on any of the hosts to see if it is reporting any problems

Comment: @MadsHansen It worked with docker-compose. Not feeling the need to check now.